# How to load a .json file from another website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, cross-domain

I need to get a json file from a website: "http://fipeapi.appspot.com/api/1/carros/marcas.json" that doesn't implement JSONP callback function, it only returns several errors.

I've tried to get using a JSON call and returns error "200 OK" because of the crossdomain issue, i've already tried JSONP too, but it returns "parsererror" because the remote server doesn't wrap the response on a callback function.

There's some way to get this content or it's impossible?

Comment: Use a server side proxy

Comment: Note, the "server side proxy" doesn't actually have to be on your server. YQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Musa and Kevin B, you can use a proxy server script that will wrap the actual source you're trying to get in JSONP or CORS. For example [JSONProxy](http://jsonp.jit.su/) allows you to request

```
http://jsonp.jit.su/?callback=myCallback&url=http://fipeapi.appspot.com/api/1/carros/marcas.json
```

Which will return the data wrapped in a call to myCallback(). The site also supports CORS if you prefer that, there's some examples in the link I provided above.